# Как i получает значение 3 если в массиве 4 элемента?

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

```js
const users_account = [{
    name: 'Вася',
    login: 'Vasya123',
    password: 'Vasya'
  },
  {
    name: 'Петя',
    login: 'Petya123',
    password: 'Petya'
  },
  {
    name: 'Дима',
    login: 'Dima123',
    password: 'Dima'
  },
  {
    name: 'Тима',
    login: 'Tima123',
    password: 'Tima'
  }
]
// const и let можно заменить на var если вы этого не проходили ещё
let user_asw = {
  login: prompt('login'),
  password: prompt('password')
}

for (let i = 0; i < users_account.length; i++) {
  if (user_asw.login === users_account[i].login &&
    user_asw.password === users_account[i].password) {
    alert('Привет, ' + users_account[i].name);
    break;
  } else if ( ** i ** === users_account.length - 1 ** ) {
    alert('Такого пользователя нету :( ');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нумерация значений в массивах начинается с нуля:

```js
const array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

console.log(array[0])
// one

console.log(array[3])
// four

console.log(array.length)
// 4
```

А `i` в Вашем цикле начинается с нуля `let i = 0`, который заканчиваться когда достигает длинны массива (4), т.е первый прогон `i -> 0`, второй `i -> 1`, третий `i -> 2`, четвертый `i -> 3`.

---

Если вычитать единицу:

```
} else if (i === users_account.length - 1) {
  alert("Такого пользователя нету")
}
```

то `i` будет равно от 1 до 3, а длинна массива будет равна 4 - 1, т.е `i === 3`.

Вопрос в том какая именно проверка и на что Вам нужна.

Comment: Мой вопрос изменили, я задавал вопрос , как i получает значение меньше чем длина. Ведь итеррация записывается в i , соответственно если i == 4, то и users_account.length тоже должел быть 4? в моем примере делается users_account.length -1 , Тогда как else if (  i === users_account.length - 1  ) это выражение не верно должно быть? Надеюсь объяснил правильно.

Comment: @IslamIbrakhimzhanov, выведи внутри цикла значения `i`, `users_account.length` и `users_account.length - 1` и посмотри что, на какой итерации выводится

Comment: @IslamIbrakhimzhanov `если i === 4, то и users_account.length тоже должен быть 4` в данном конкретном случае `i` не будет равно 4 внутри цикла, максимум чему оно будет равно внутри это 3, поэтому что бы сочеталось (в случаях когда это требуется) вычитают из длинны единицу

Comment: "не будет равно 4 внутри цикла, максимум чему оно будет равно внутри это 3".
 Вопрос почему? Ведь он проходи весь массив. Не понятия возникает именно в этот момент. Почему он не равен 4?

Comment: @IslamIbrakhimzhanov я подробно объяснил это в первой части моего ответа

Comment: Вот теперь понял. Дошло наконец-то. В первом ответе все было четко написано.